# cURL in wamp - 415 unsupported media type AdWords

Tags: curl, wamp, media, google-ads-api

I am using version 201302 of theAdwords API. I have WAMP Server version 2.2 installed and since curl was not working out if the box, I also installed curl from http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/.
cURL started to work fine, however whenever I try to run an example from the Adwords API library I get an Unsupported Media Type error. The example I am trying to run is the one in reports/GetCampaignStats.php in the library files.
I put the same example in a remote server and it runs flawlesly in there so it has to be something in my local environment but I can't find what could it be. 
Has anyone had this problem and knows what to do in order to fix it?

PHP version: 5.4.3

Thanks a lot in advance!